# Manhattan Distance for two geolocations

Tags: distance

Let's say I have two locations represented by latitude and longitude.
Location 1 : `37.5613` , `126.978`
Location 2 : `37.5776` , `126.973`

How can I calculate the distance using Manhattan distance ?

Edit : I know the formula for calculating Manhattan distance like stated by `Emd4600` on the answer which is `|x1-x2| - |y1-y2|` but I think it's for Cartesian. If it is can be applied that straight forward `|37.5613-37.5776| + |126.978-126.973|` what is the distance unit of the result ?

Comment: The 2nd question is easily answered once you know the distance in km (divide by the speed in km/h). But only if you assume that oceans, mountain ranges and other non-street surfaces do not slow down your travelling.

Comment: Yeah I know the 2nd question can easily answered using the very basic formulation T = S / V

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a plane with `p1` at `(x1, y1)` and `p2` at `(x2, y2)`, it is, the formula to calculate the Manhattan Distance is `|x1 - x2| + |y1 - y2|`. (that is, the difference between the latitudes and the longitudes). So, in your case, it would be:

```
|126.978 - 126.973| + |37.5613 - 37.5776| = 0.0213
```

EDIT: As you have said, that would give us the difference in latitude-longitude units. Basing on [this webpage](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), this is what I think you must do to convert it to the metric system. I haven't tried it, so I don't know if it's correct:

First, we get the latitude difference:

```
Δφ = |Δ2 - Δ1|
Δφ = |37.5613 - 37.5776| = 0.0163
```

Now, the longitude difference:

```
Δλ = |λ2 - λ1|
Δλ = |126.978 - 126.973| = 0.005
```

Now, we will use the `haversine` formula. In the webpage it uses `a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)`, but that would give us a straight-line distance. So to do it with Manhattan distance, we will do the latitude and longitude distances separately.

First, we get the latitude distance, as if longitude was 0 (that's why a big part of the formula got omitted):

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
latitudeDistance = R ⋅ c // R is the Earth's radius, 6,371km
```

Now, the longitude distance, as if the latitude was 0:

```
a = sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
longitudeDistance = R ⋅ c // R is the Earth's radius, 6,371km
```

Finally, just add up `|latitudeDistance| + |longitudeDistance|`.

Comment: if I add `0.005 + 0.0163` it would be `0.0213` what is the distance unit of the number ? that's the main question actually.

Comment: I don't think this is a solution. I have two locations 
`lat1 : 37.4602 , lng1 : 126.441` and `lat2: 37.5567 , lng2 : 126.924` the real distance is about `54.12km` but your equation gives me `3691.9945 km`. It is such a huge difference. And I am curious, why you omitted `+ cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)` in both latitude and longitude calculations ?

Comment: after I converted the `latitude` and `longitude` from `degree` to `radian` when calculating the distance using `Haversine` formula the distance became `64.437459990522 km`

Comment: I omitted that part of the formula because we were calculating `latitude` and `longitude` separatedly. That is, when we calculated one, the other was 0 in the formula, and so it was useless to put it there.

Comment: Wait, how is this correct? You should set the difference of latitudes (Δφ = 0) and the difference of longitude to 0 (Δλ = 0). Not each latitude and longitude to 0. So you have proper 'hinge' between the two coordinates. So, for the case for longitude distance you would have cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2) What you are doing is adding two haversine distance between (x1, 0) (x2, 0) and (0, y1) (0, y2) and that is not the same as the manhattan distance betwen the two points.

Answer (score 2):

For example, calculating Manhattan Distance of Point1 and Point2.
Simply apply LatLng distance function by projecting the "Point2" on to the same Lat or Lng of the "Point1".

```
def distance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, coordinates):

    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    lon1 = radians(lng1)
    lon2 = radians(lng2)
    d_lon = lon2 - lon1
    d_lat = lat2 - lat1

    if coordinates['LatLong']:
        r = 6373.0
        a = (np.sin(d_lat/2.0))**2 + np.cos(lat1) * \
            np.cos(lat2) * (np.sin(d_lon/2.0))**2
        c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
        total_distance = r * c

    if coordinates['XY']:
        total_distance = math.sqrt(d_lon * d_lon + d_lat * d_lat)
    return total_distance

def latlng2manhattan(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
    coordinates = {"LatLong": True, "XY": False}
    # direction = 1
    if lat1 == 0:
        lat1 = lat2
        # if lng1 < lng2:
            # direction = -1
    if lng1 == 0:
        lng1 = lng2
        # if lat1 < lat2:
            # direction = -1
    # mh_dist = direction * distance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, coordinates) * 3280.84 # km to ft
    mh_dist = distance(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, coordinates) * 3280.84
    return mh_dist

df["y_mh"] = df["y_lat"].apply(lambda x: latlng2manhattan(0, x, center_long, center_lat))
df["x_mh"] = df["x_long"].apply(lambda x: latlng2manhattan(x, 0, center_long, center_lat))
```

Comment: Btw, I was converting LatLng coordinate to another coordinate system.  The code can be simplified if only for getting distance purpose.